# How to checkbox without button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

how to checkbox without button and if the user does not check something is going return null.

How I called data from the check box

1. I called the data from the adapter with using a statement.
2. is send the data to interface with layout position
3. I called all layout data in my loop
4. I converted string to double to get sum all value is checked.

This is my task with using the button. I called this from the adapter.

I declared checkbox in my adapter:

```
holder.setItemCheckBox(new CheckboxListener() {
        @Override
        public void respond(View v, int position) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;

            double checkedSum = 0;

            //Check if checked or not

            if(chk.isChecked()){

                checkdata.add(catalogDatabases.get(position));

            }else if(!chk.isChecked()){

                checkdata.remove(catalogDatabases.get(position));

            }
        }
    });
```

This is my interface :

```
public interface CheckboxListener {

void respond (View v, int position);
}
```

[image]

Comment: plz state your problem properly..

Comment: Can you please clarify your question in more details? Given details is not enough for us to exactly identify your question.

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA done edit in question

Comment: so is your app crashing?? or what is the expected output....provide us your expected output and obtained output

Comment: expected ouptut but i dont want using clicklistener to get output